# What's the expected lifespan for an ankle support?

Tags: ankle, home-medical-equipment

I wonder what the expected lifespan is for an ankle support. A friend of mine has been using one for a few months, and it starts falling apart every 6 weeks or so (see picture below). Also, the ankle support tend to loosen over time.

[image]

Are ankle supports made to be used to prolonged period of times, like a few months or more?

Comment: <comments deleted> [Please do not leave answers in the comments.](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/378/26) Instead, it would be appreciated if you leave an actual answer (with references) below.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off topic.

Comment: @Thomas questions about medical equipment are perfectly on topic

Comment: Not really something that goes into medical sciences per se imo, but then, also lacks prior research or sources thereof. Probably easiest to answer via asking the manufacturer or distributor; if not, then opinion-based.

Comment: @Thomas I'm interested to know for ankle supports in general, not for a specific brand/model. The question was asked over 5  years ago when the "lacks prior research" wasn't a reason to close, and when the website was called "Health".